# CAPTCHA Popup test

Tags: computer-puzzle, cryptic-clues

Solve the cryptic clue.

> Hidden finance equals to nothing (3, abbr.)

Notice the capitalization in your answer.
Make sure your capitalization is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> NaN?

Because

> it's hidden in "fi**nan**ce", and equals to "nothing" in the sense of "not a number".

I don't understand the significance of the title though.

Comment: That's my intended answer, but the site has a glitch. If the site required you to pass CAPTCHA when you posted the answer, inform us.

Comment: @Scratch---Cat I don't remember the last time this site required me to do a Captcha test. Isn't it normally something like "click all boxes that contain cars"?

Comment: Vf gur BC ybbxvat sbe lbh gb fnl, "Abg n Ebobg?"